# Conditional downcast to CoreFoundation type 'CGColor' will always succeed

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, uicolor

When I call the following function, I get 2 errors:

> 1.Conditional downcast to CoreFoundation type 'CGColor' will always succeed
>
> 2.Cannot assign value of type 'CGColor?' to type 'UIColor?'

I am just starting out, I converted this from old objective C code using Swiftify.  I want the colors to cycle, its called at`ViewDidLoad`  method.

Thanks

```
func doBackgroundColorAnimation() {
    
    var i: Int = 0
    let colors = [UIColor.green, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.orange, UIColor.red]
    
    if i >= colors.count {
        i = 0
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {() -> Void in
        view.backgroundColor = colors[i] as? CGColor
    }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
        i
        self.doBackgroundColorAnimation()
    })
}
```

Comment: write  view.backgroundColor = colors[i] instead of  view.backgroundColor = colors[i] as? CGColor. There is no need to convert UIColor from CGColor

Comment: Hi, this creates this error: Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit.  So, I add self.view.backgroundColor but I get another Expression resolves to an unused l-value error due to 'I'? Thanks

Comment: remove i from completion handler

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome.....!!!

Comment: I am trying to get the background to fade/blend between the colors from the array - every 2 seconds, green, yellow, etc.  The code is now "fixed", but doesn't do what I am looking for - currently, the bg image always stays at 0 (Green). I am not telling it to cycle through each color correctly it seems?

Answer (score 0):

*Here are many mistakes with the code snippet:*

**1: It seems like you want to assign color:**

You can assign color object simply by `view.backgroundColor = colors[i]`

Also, If You want CGColor from UICooor so get it by `colors[i].cgColor`

**2: NOTE:**

> The UIColor class doesn't inherit from the CGColor that's why it's
>   unable to downcast from the UIColor.

**The Inheritance** `UIKit -> Drawing -> UIColor`

**3: Remove `i` from Completion.**

**4: Add self in the animated block `self.view.backgroundColor`**